# Azure Authentication (classic): AAD multiple issuer url

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-authentication

I have set up B2C Azure Authentication for my azure function works fine and looks like this:
[image]

It works well, user can log in and call APIs all fine!

Now I want to call the same APIs from some other web API. I implemented it with `client_credentials`, i.e. I call `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<b2c>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token` with client id and secret and get token.

API response fails with 401 `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`. I found out it's because the issuer is different (obviously), if I call API from a logged-in user issuer is `https://<b2c>.b2clogin.com/<tenant id>/v2.0/` VS client credentials flow issuer is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/v2.0`.

So I changed my settings like so:
[image]

Now call from an external web app doesn't fail. But it fails for users, that logged in as b2c flow!

How can I configure Issuer Url, so that it works in both flows: when the user sign-in-up flow via b2c and external API with client credentials flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sample here

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/apps/blob/master/apps/spa-hellojs-popup/source-code/.Net-Core-API-RBAC/MultiBearerAPI/Startup.cs#L30

This api allows tokens from two different issuers.

You can’t achieve this with the Authentication options in the Azure Portal as it only allows one issuer.

Comment: I see, so this will require validation of token by myself in azure function :( thanks

Comment: @Jas Suri - MSFT Is there any option yet to achieve this same via Portal or still there is just one option as mentioned above (through code)? 

I have read in multiple documents that there is a default issuer we can use when there are multiple - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0 but that doesn't work for me. Appreciate your response on this. Thanks.